# mod-rewrite not working on live server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a simple RewriteRule below that's working fine on my local machine but it doesn't work when I uploaded to my live server.

**Error:**

> Not Found The requested URL
>   /redirect:/jobs.php/1/field-engineer.php/1/field-engineer.php was not
>   found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**.htaccess:**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule jobs/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ jobs.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule testimonial-details/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ testimonial-details.php?id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule testimonials/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ testimonials.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check if your rewrite module was loaded?
Btw you should check it in your htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
// your rewrite stuff here
</IfModule>
```

Edit:

Maybe this could help. Try to set the PT flag to your first rewrite rule

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1.php [NC,PT]`

That will tell the engine to make a clean second path on the generated URL. Because there is a weird behaviour according to you rule.

The url

`jobs/1/civil-engineer.html` is rewritten as `jobs/1/civil-engineer.php`

but the following rule

`jobs/([0-9]+)/(.*)/` is waiting to for an url like `jobs/1/civil-engineer.php/`

I did some testing but removing the '/' only avoided certain errors, but the behavious was still weird. The only way i found was to add the PT flag or to change the rule for

`RewriteRule jobs/([0-9]+)/(.*)\?php jobs.php?id=$1`

Comment: yes, it's working on live server. also, the last RewriteRues is working... RewriteRule testimonials/([0-9]+)/(.*)/ testimonials.php?id=$1 [NC]... but the other two does not. Thanks

Comment: What is the link that was rewrited as `/redirect:/jobs.php/1/field-engineer.php/1/field-engineer.php`

Comment: localhost/jobs/1/civil-engineer.html and the code-> $jobs_url = WEBSITE_URL . 'jobs/' . $row->job_id   . '/' . $helper->format_url_keyword($row->position) . '.html';

Comment: I suppose WEBSITE_URL change according to your website domain name. Sorry i don't have a clue, the rule seems right.

Comment: sorry, the WEBSITE_URL is equivalent to 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/' - it's defined on my global-config.php. Thanks